# How bash treats Here-docs

Tags: c, bash

I'm working on a modest bash-like shell in C and I have a question on here-doc. For the moment my shell can execute here-doc only in first command.

`ls | << eof wc`

**bash result :**

```
> eof
0 0 0
```

**my result :**

```
> eof
10 10 63
```

(`wc` takes the result of `ls`, I have problem in my pipes but can't figure what.)

In this case, I can just do like `ls` doesn't exist I think.

`wc | << eof wc`

**bash result**

```
> eof
0 0 0
```

Here, bash executes the command with here-doc in first and execute the second (which it doesn't has input so it's freezing).

**my result**

```
> eof
```

I execute the here-doc first like `bash`, and eof works, but I have no result and then it's freezing due to the first `wc`.

So can I treat all cases like that? I execute the command with here doc first and cancel others except if they have to crash (like `wc` if it has no input)?

Comment: `bash` is a particular shell. If you are writing your own shell, it's not `bash`. That said, how are you actually implementing the here doc? In `bash`, the redirection from a here document takes precedence over the pipe, so `wc` is basically just ignoring whatever `ls` writes to the pipe and reading from the here document instead.

Comment: Read the POSIX sh spec for a definitive description of how a shell is supposed to behave. Don't try to work backwards from observing behavior.

Comment: From Section 2.9.2 of the POSIX specification for the shell command language: " The standard input, standard output, or both of a command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline before any redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the command (see Redirection)."

Comment: @chepner I write in stdin with a equivalent of readline, put this in a pipe, and I give the pipe for input when the commands with here_doc comes

Comment: `wc` doesn't know it is part of a pipeline. Without the here document, it would receive the read end of the pipe as its standard input. With the here document, it receives the here document *instead*; it never sees the pipe, because the shell makes the switch before `wc` starts. As for `ls`, I'm not sure if it blocks when it writes (waiting for someone to open the other end of the pipe) or if it receives SIGPIPE (because the other end has already been closed).

Comment: I _suspect_ that the OP's shell is still keeping an open FD on the read end of the pipeline (potentially on a different, nonzero file descriptor). But without a [mre], that's just guesswork. Either way, it's not appropriate to try to "cancel" other pipeline elements -- if you do it right the copy of `ls` _should_ be getting an error because it's writing to a closed file descriptor and exiting on its own because of that, without the shell needing to do anything explicit to kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a POSIX shell, redirections such as here-docs are associated with commands, and the pipe operator (`|`) separates commands.  Thus here:

```
ls | << eof wc
eof
```

the here-doc is associated with the second command, `wc` (even though the redirection operator appears before the command name).  It redirects that command's standard input to be from the content of the here-doc.  The pipe operator also affects the second command's standard input, so an important question is which effect is applied last, as that is the one that will be effective.  [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02) for a pipeline of the form `command1 | command2`:

> The standard output of `command1` shall be connected to the standard
> input of `command2`. **The standard input, standard output, or both of a
> command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline *before* any
> redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the
> command**.

(Emphasis added.)  For what it's worth, the Bash docs say the same in their own words.

For your example, then, the here-doc should replace the output of `ls` as the input to `wc`, as it does when Bash processes the command.

---

> In this case, I can just do like ls doesn't exist I think.
>
> ```
> wc | << eof wc
> ```
>
> **bash result**
>
> ```
> > eof
> 0 0 0
> ```
>
> Here, bash executes the command with here-doc in first and execute the second (which it doesn't has input so it's freezing).

Not exactly.  The heredoc belongs to the *second* `wc` command, not the first, so it is the first that hangs waiting for interactive input.  You can cause that to finish normally by typing a ctrl-D.

More importantly, if the idea is to ignore the `ls`, then why use two `wc` commands?  Just drop the `ls` and the pipeline altogether, and use a single `wc` command:

```
<<eof wc
eof

# OR, equivalently and more conventionally,

wc <<eof
eof
```

> So can I treat all cases like that? I execute the command with here
> doc first and cancel others except if they have to crash (like wc if
> it has no input)?

You seem to be trying to create specific rules where you should instead be observing more general ones.  Each command has standard input, output, and error that are initially either inherited from the host shell or assigned as directed by pipe operators.  Redirections, including from here-docs, are each part of an individual command, and their effects are applied on top of the initial standard stream assignments for that command.  When multiple redirections apply to the same command, they are processed from left to right.

You cannot "cancel" commands based on the status of their standard streams.  They will do whatever they do with the streams they receive.  That might be nothing at all, terminating with an error, or exactly what they would have done anyway, among other possibilities.  The shell doesn't know, so it cannot shortcut this.